# Converting bitrate of audio mp3 file which is playing online through link using android studio java

Tags: java, android-studio, mp3, bitrate

I am trying to change the bitrate of mp3 file which is playing online through link. As I have to change the audio streaming quality in android application. I have searched on it and found ffmpeg solution. But not got any suitable solution to implement this functionality.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

**The audio streaming quality depends on the file you are playing, not the client application.**
You will have to create a server-side solution to convert the audio file to a lower bitrate.

You can however download the file and convert it to a lower bitrate after, but I don't see the need for that as you will have a high quality version stored already.

Comment: I have to give audio streaming quality settings at client end. And want to play audio on lower quality if user set quality at low.

Comment: @ZubariaAshraf in that case you'll need to have the audio in several versions (qualities) on server side

Comment: Usually you have several versions of the file indeed. audio_320.mp3, audio_192.mp3, audio_96.mp3 etc.